# How to say 100,500

Tags: british-english

How do you say the number 100,500?  Is it one hundred thousand five hundred?  For some reason that doesn't sound write in my mind.  The number 10,500 is ten thousand five hundred.  Please correct me if I am wrong about 10,500.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is **not** about *and* use.

Comment: This may be of help.  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pdsZ_zHdaekJ:http://www.4cke.com/uploads/4/1/4/5/41455/chapter_resources_grade_4_chapter_2.pdf%2B100500+%22one+hundred+thousand+*%22&hl=en&gbv=2&ct=clnk

Comment: @Kris This question is about how to say the number 100,500, which the duplicate answers.

Comment: @KitFox http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110799/how-to-say-100-500?noredirect=1#comment224920_110799

Comment: @Kris The question is "How do you say the number 100,500?  Is it one hundred thousand five hundred?" which is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: What is the alternative for 100,500? (which is to say 'one hundred thousand five hundred' is the correct way  to say it)

Answer (score 2):

"One hundred thousand, five hundred" would be correct. Also, *right.